# Generic duration meter for any operator, function call and constructor

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++-chrono

I was using a templatized *meter* function (see below) to measure the elapsed time for functions.
Then I also wanted to use it for constructors.

As far as I know there is no way of passing a type as a function parameter directly. So I came up with this workaround, passing it solely as the template parameter (minimal example):

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ... P>
auto meter(T t, P ... p) {
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    t(p...);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dif = t2-t1;   
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(dif);
}

template <typename T, typename ... P>
auto meter(P ... p) {
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t = T(p...);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dif = t2-t1;   
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(dif);
}

int main() {
    auto d = meter(g, 1.0, 20.0); //meter the function call g(1.0, 20.0)
    std::cout << "Ellapsed time: " << d.count() << " microseconds\n";
    d = meter(complex_obj{2}); //meter () operator of complex_obj, assuming complex_obj{int} is trivial;
    std::cout << "Ellapsed time: " << d.count() << " microseconds\n";
    d = meter<complex_obj>(); //meter constructor complex_obj();
    std::cout << "Ellapsed time: " << d.count() << " microseconds\n";
}
```

Trying this got me thinking. Is there a general/consistent way of rewriting this, as to apply to any kind of computation (not just constructor, but maybe even other operators like (obj1 < obj2)? I noticed, that I was already (accidentally) supporting the () operator of structs.

Sorry if this question became to broad, my main question is, if there is a way to unite the syntax of *meter* call, for functions and constructors alike.

Comment: Just an idea: If you'd like to measure a series of operations where the functions you measure are returning a value, you'd probably like to let your meter function actually return that value (and "return" the duration in a duration reference passed to `meter`). That could also allow for RVO through your meter function. You'd still affect performance by your measurements (as always) but perhaps not to the same extent.

Comment: Could clarify what sort of syntax you'd like to use for comparisons?

Comment: `g` is a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the code to be measured inside a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (since C++11):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template<class F>
auto meter(F&& f) {
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  f();//                                                <-- operator() of the lambda
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto dif = t2-t1;
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(dif);
}

void g(double x, double y) {
  std::cout << "g(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n";
}

int main() {
  double x = 1.0;
  auto d = meter([&] {
    // This comment is inside the *body* of the lambda.
    // Code of the {body} is executed upon `operator()`.
    g(x, 20.0);// note that you can use `x` here thanks to the capture-default `[&]`
  });
  std::cout << "time: " << d.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

However you encapsulate the actual function call, it'll probably be for the best if you make your `meter` function return the value returned by the function it's measuring to make it possible to chain calls - but still with the possibility to check how long time each individual call took afterwards. This makes it theoretically possible for RVO / copy elision to kick in and therefor not slow down the code as much. Example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> // for debug sleeps only

using namespace std::chrono;

template<typename D, typename F, typename... P>
auto meter(D& dur, F func, P&&... params) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto retval = func(std::forward<P>(params)...);
    // put duration in the duration reference
    dur = duration_cast<D>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    // and return func()'s return value
    return retval;
}

namespace m {
double add(double a, double b) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(10));
    return a + b;
}
double sub(double a, double b) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(11));
    return a - b;
}
double mul(double a, double b) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(12));
    return a * b;
}
double div(double a, double b) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(13));
    return a / b;
}
} // namespace m

int main() {
    milliseconds Add, Sub, Mul, Div;

    // chaining calls for this calculation:
    // (1000 / (100 * (4.3 - (1.1+2.2))))
    auto result = meter(Div, m::div,
        1000.0, meter(Mul, m::mul,
            100.0, meter(Sub, m::sub,
                4.3, meter(Add, m::add,
                    1.1, 2.2)
                )
        )
    );
    std::cout << "Add: " << Add.count() << " ms.\n";
    std::cout << "Sub: " << Sub.count() << " ms.\n";
    std::cout << "Mul: " << Mul.count() << " ms.\n";
    std::cout << "Div: " << Div.count() << " ms.\n";
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Probable output:

```
Add: 10 ms.
Sub: 11 ms.
Mul: 12 ms.
Div: 13 ms.
10
```